# Can we see built in class and interfaces of Apex in an IDE?

Tags: apex, ide

Is there any way to see all built in classes and interfaces as we can see in NetBeans for Java?

Comment: By "see" do you mean an equivalent of Javadoc?

Comment: As we can see built in classes on netBeans by (ctrl + clicking)  on built in className in java. Means what is written in standard built in classes and in built in interfaces ....

Comment: I've modified your question to be more specific. Please re-edit if I've got it wrong.

Comment: No issue,Thanks, now its better.... for understanding... 
so is there any way...?

Answer (score 2):

There are several code editors for Apex typically built into an IDE and what you are looking for is a feature of those. The Apex can be parsed locally to offer code completions, but it is the Salesforce server that has a full (and up to date) model of the Apex source code, the platform provided APIs, the SObjects and other component definitions. So using a server API such as the relatively new [Tooling API](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/api_tooling.pdf)'s "code completions" is a good way for the editor to go.

The code editor in the [Developer Console](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_dev_console_view_code_editor.htm&language=en_US) supports this feature.

Of the available IDE's that support this feature, [MavensMate](http://mavensmate.com/) is frequently recommended. Support for this feature is [work in progress](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/issues/20) in the [Force.com IDE](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE) provided by Salesforce. There are other editors/IDEs too that others may comment on.

Here is an example of the code completion available in the Developer Console:

[image: Developer Consoled code completion]

Comment: Thanks for your response @Keith C, i used force.com iDE in eclipse. But in this ide where i can view schedulable interface and other things, for example when we use list<string> Lstr;   Lstr.size() returns size of collection and size method is defined somewhere in library so where i can see standard built in list collection size() method. are u getting my question....

Comment: @AmitChaudhary The Force.com IDE is behind other editors/IDEs at the moment (and what you get depends on what version you are using). I've added a screen shot from the Developer Console that shows the list size method and the same code completion is available in MavensMate.

Comment: This shows size() method return type and parameter, i want to see defination of this method..

Comment: @AmitChaudhary In Java, Eclipse code completion also links you into the Javadoc (which is nice but not critical), but there isn't a direct equivalent to Javadoc for Apex. The Apex code completion provides the signature - the method name and parameter names and types - and that most of the time gives you all the information you need - `size` and `sort` are pretty self documenting. If you need more detail you'll have to Google for it.